# Convert query to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter. I want to know, how to write below code in codeigniter..

```
SELECT p.* FROM people p WHERE p.age = (select max(subp.age) from people subp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
$this->db->select('p.*');
$this->db->from('people p');
$this->db->where('p.age = (select max(subp.age) from people subp)',null,false);
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: what if subquery returns multiple rows

Comment: @SureshK you can `limit` value to one

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this such as

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.* FROM people p WHERE p.age = (select max(subp.age) from people subp)';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result_array();
```